# How do I call Codeigniters 2 Active record to get 2 sets of results from the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am essentially creating a chunking function for a file export, and I have a select->from->where that I have built already. I want to be able to call 'get' twice each time with different limit/offset values.

Here's a walk-through of the basic idea.

```
// BallReport.php
function ProcessData(){
    //Report 1
    $query = createSelectQuery();
    $query = applyReportOneWhereValues($query);
    $results1 = CSVTool::processLargeDataSet($query, 10, 1000);

    //Report 2
    $query = createSelectQuery();
    $query = applyReportTwoWhereValues($query);
    $results2 = CSVTool::processLargeDataSet($query, 10, 1000);
}

function createSelectQuery(){
    // the select is complicated having multiple joins and sub queries 
    // so I only want to have to write this once
    $query = $this->db->select('ball.name,
            color.name,
            size.name,
            shape.name')
        ->from('ball')
        ->join('color', 'ball.color_id = color.id')
        ->join('size', 'ball.size_id = size.id')
        ->join('shape', 'ball.shape_id = shape.id');
    return $query;
}

function applyReportOneWhereValues($query){
    // I have 2 different sets of where parameters
    // But they are both using the same select
    // so I separated them into these functions
    // So I can apply the set of where statements
    // all at once
    $query = $query->where("table.color", "blue")
                   ->where("table.size" , "large")
                   ->where("table.shape", "round");
    return $query;
}

function applyReportTwoWhereValues($query){
    $query = $query->where("table.color", "red")
                   ->where("table.size" , "small")
                   ->where("table.shape", "round");
    return $query;
}

//In CSVTool.php 
public static function processLargeDataSet($query, $numberOfPages, $chunkSize){
    // Since the data set is going to be so large we want to process in chunks 
    // So that we don't hit the limit and break mid way. 
    // To do that we only call the DB in sets of 1000 rows
    for(int $i = 0; $i <= $numberOfPages: $i++){
        processRows($query, $i * $chunkSize, $chunkSize);
    }
}

function processRows($query, $offset, $limit){
    // We limit in here so each time it's called we change the offset and limit
    $query = $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit);
    $valuesToProcess = $query->get()->result_array();

    // process the rows here
}
```

this of course doesn't work because once processRows calls $query->get() the first time all subsequent calls throws a `Query error: No tables used`

Is there any solution for this? Is there a chunking function in Codeigniter 2 that I'm unaware of?

Comment: did you try in your methods `applyReportOneWhereValues($query)`, `applyReportTwoWhereValues($query)`, etc make this `$query .= $query->...` because you never concatenate the query variable and re-declaret it in every method

Comment: @elddenmedio So when calling each by itself they work perfectly, they do exactly what I expect. I use them with a limit 20 to display them in a table already. So I know it is working the way I have it. The issue is when we get to process rows, where it calls get() and then when it calls the second one it breaks. If we exit right after the first processRows() everything works fine.

Comment: @elddenmedio I could also have used function chaining instead of `$query = $query->where()` I could do `$query->where()->where()->where();` or something like that. I'm Positive it's something to do with calling get() clearing the query, because when it's called again it doesn't know what table to pull from.

Comment: How are you using this code in Codeigniter? And is this the same exact code you are using?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am building on top of codeigniter to build a CSV chunking export I need to be able to dump 200k rows as a CSV for a report at work. So I am building a tool that takes a query as a parameter, and then dynamically builds the offset and limit into the query so that it can dump a date range. And no this is not the exact same code I'm using, the code I'm using is significantly longer than this, but I have made sure that the essentials are detailed, passing queries to functions, adding filters based on conditions, I just updated to add more complex joins from other feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new answer to the revised question.

```
public function ProcessData()
{
    //Report 1
    $query_builder = $this->applyReportOneWhereValues($this->createSelectQuery());
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $results1 = CSVTool::processLargeDataSet($query_builder, 10, 1000);
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    //Report 2
    $query_builder = $this->applyReportTwoWhereValues($this->createSelectQuery());
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $results2 = CSVTool::processLargeDataSet($query_builder, 10, 1000);
    $this->db->flush_cache(); //just to be safe
}

public function createSelectQuery()
{
    $this->db->start_cache();
    return $this->db->select('ball.name, color.name, size.name, shape.name')
        ->join('color', 'ball.color_id = color.id')
        ->join('size', 'ball.size_id = size.id')
        ->join('shape', 'ball.shape_id = shape.id');
}

public function applyReportOneWhereValues($query_builder)
{
    return $query_builder
      ->where("table.color", "blue")
      ->where("table.size", "large")
      ->where("table.shape", "round");
}

public function applyReportTwoWhereValues($query_builder)
{
    return $query_builder
      ->where("table.color", "red")
      ->where("table.size", "small")
      ->where("table.shape", "round");
}
```

In CSVTool.php

```
/**
 * Process the records in chunks
 * @param CI_DB_query_builder $qb An instance of the CI_DB_query_builder class
 * @param int $numberOfPages The number of pages to create in the set (1 to n)
 * @param int $pageSize The number of records per page
 */
public static function processLargeDataSet($qb, $numberOfPages, $pageSize)
{
    if($numberOfPages < 1)
    {
        $numberOfPages = 1;
    }
    for($i = 1; $i < $numberOfPages; $i++)
    {
        $valuesToProcess = $qb
          ->get('ball', $pageSize, $i - 1 * $pageSize)
          ->result_array();
        // process the rows in $valuesToProcess
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is "Active Record Caching". This could be managed from a couple different places. In this answer it is in `ProcessData()`

Note:
You were assigning lots of things to the same var `$query` and passing it around a lot for no good reason I can see. And you are often overwriting `$query` with the exact same value multiple times in a row. I have used `$this->db` in most of the places you used `$query`.

```
public function ProcessData()
{
    //Report 1
    $this->db->start_cache();
    //createSelectQuery(); not needed if you want all fields from one table
    applyReportOneWhereValues();
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    processLargeDataSet(10, 1000);

    //Report 2
    $this->db->flush_cache()
    $this->db->start_cache();
    //createSelectQuery(); not needed if you want all fields from one table
    applyReportTwoWhereValues();
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    processLargeDataSet(10, 1000);
    $this->db->flush_cache();
}
```

Your question uses `select("*")` and `from("table_name")` which can be eliminated if you really want all fields from one table. When `get("table_name")` is used and there is no `select()` call then all fields are assumed. IOW, the query statement would be `SELECT * FROM 'table_name';`

Based on the question's code it seems you don't need the `createSelectQuery()` function.

Your "apply where" functions but re-written using method chaining.

```
public function applyReportOneWhereValues()
{
    $this->db
      ->where("table.color", "blue")
      ->where("table.size", "large")
      ->where("table.shape", "round");
}

public function applyReportTwoWhereValues()
{
    $this->db
      ->where("table.color", "red")
      ->where("table.size", "small")
      ->where("table.shape", "round");
}
```

I have eliminated `processRows()` and incorporated that logic into `processLargeDataSet()`. Notice how `get()` is used - passing a table name, limit, and offset - to remove the need for `select()`, `from()`, `limit()`, and `offset()` calls.

```
/**
 * Process the records in chunks
 * @param int $numberOfPages The number of pages to create in the set (1 to n)
 * @param int $pageSize The number of records per page
 */
function processLargeDataSet($numberOfPages, $pageSize)
{
    if($numberOfPages < 1)
    {
        $numberOfPages = 1;
    }
    for($i = 1; $i < $numberOfPages; $i++)
    {
        $valuesToProcess = $this->db
          ->get('table', $pageSize, ($i-1) * $pageSize)
          ->result_array();
        // process the rows in $valuesToProcess
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll work! Except for a couple of little whoopsies... 1. $this->db->flush_cache()->start_cache() doesn't seem to like being chained. Works with separate statements. 2. Need a $i for  i * $pageSize. 3. Should it not be $i < $numberOfPages, in the case $numberOfPages = 10 we want 0 to 9?

Comment: I've edited the answer to fixed the whoopsies.Thanks @TimBrownlaw. As to `$numberOfPages`,,, it has been revised to handle values of `1 to n`.

Comment: So I don't want all the fields from one table, as I mentioned the query is more complicated, I updated the original to have joins to 3 other tables. I also changed mine to use chaining.

Comment: I originally didn't use chaining because I use a tool I've written that scans my input array for keys and returns an updated query object like `$query = InputTool::FilterWhere($query, $arr, 'color.color_id')` for example returns the query object with a where() added if it finds the key `color.color_id` in the array.

Comment: I think the record caching concept remains valid. Do you want a revised answer?

Comment: I think it's okay, I managed to get it to work using `$tempQuery = clone $query` in the processRows function earlier this morning. I have to look further into the caching thing though cause it might work better

Comment: I think it will work better. Less memory and processing involved.

Comment: So since I am using joins, I run `createSelectQuery()` first then `start_cache(); applyReportOneWhereValues(); stop_cache(); processLargeDataSet();` then before I call `applyReportTwoWhereValues();` I call `flush_cache()` and then repeat, start, apply, stop and then after the finial process I'd probably want to flush again just to be safe

Comment: The `select` needs to be cached too or it will not persist between `get()` calls.

Comment: I still think `->get('table', $pageSize, $i-1 * $pageSize)` is a more elegant way too. But that's just my ego getting involved.